# Can not get simplest pipeline example to work in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my simple code and i am not getting it work.

I am subclassing from `initspider`

This is my code

```
class MytestSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'mytest'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    login_page = 'http://www.example.com'
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/ist.php"]

    def init_request(self):
        #"""This function is called before crawling starts."""
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['username'] = "mytest"
        return item
```

## Pipeline

```
class TestPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
            print item['username']
```

**i am geting same error if try to print the item**

The error i get is

```
 File "crawler/pipelines.py", line 35, in process_item
            myitem.username = item['username']
        exceptions.TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I the problem is with `InitSpider` . My pieplines are not getting item objects

## items.py

```
class MyItem(Item):
    username = Field()
```

## setting.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'crawler'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'spiders'


DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {

    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.cookies.CookiesMiddleware': 700 # <-
}

COOKIES_ENABLED = True
COOKIES_DEBUG = True


ITEM_PIPELINES = [

'pipelines.TestPipeline',


]

IMAGES_STORE = '/var/www/htmlimages'
```

Comment: You should post all your code for completeness (ie your item code and and your settings file). At the moment, you are creating one question with code fragments, modifying that fragment and then posting another question. For example, I have no idea why you're using models.TestUser() to create an instance of MyItem in TestPipeline.

Comment: @Talvalin , sorry for that I will post other code as well. My Model is the Django model. but we can remove that line for testing

Comment: @Talvalin , i have found that if i have otherpipeline mentioned above in the setting then i get this error

Comment: You get a different error to the one above?

Comment: @ Talvalin No the error is same. Its the second pipeline which is causing the problem. i remove the second pipeline from settings then everything works fine. Even if empty the body of other pipelines without process item function then it also works fine. but i define the process item function then i get this error. Temporarily i ahve remvoed the other pipeline so that i can get my code working

Comment: The reason you can't have both pipelines work is because the process_item must return the item to let the pipeline continue working. If you don't want to process the item anymore you need to raise DropItem. Here a snippet from the documentation:

process_item(item, spider)
This method is called for every item pipeline component and must either return a Item (or any descendant class) object or raise a DropItem exception. Dropped items are no longer processed by further pipeline components.

Answer (score 3):

`pipelines.TestPipeline` is missing order number. It should be something like `ITEM_PIPELINES = {'pipelines.TestPipeline': 900}`.

Answer (score 2):

There's another issue with your `process_item` function. According to the [official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html):

> This method is called for every item pipeline component and must either return a dict with data, Item (or any descendant class) object or raise a DropItem exception. Dropped items are no longer processed by further pipeline components.

In your case, you could add a return statement at the end of your function:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    print item['username']
    return item
```

If you don't include a return statement, the return value of this pipeline is `None`. That's why the following pipeline complains--you can't do `item['username']` when `item` is `None`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did and it worked:

1. In your `MytestSpider` class, simply write the `parse` function in this way:

   ```
   def parse(self, response):
       yield {'username': "mytest"}
   ```
2. Remove `items.py`, I didn't create any Item class and it still worked
3. In your pipeline code:

   ```
   class TestPipeline(object):

       def process_item(self, item, spider):
           print item['username']
   ```

In my testing code, it seems that everything I `yield` in the spider will become the item in Pipeline `process_item`, but the yield results has to be a dictionary, or Item object... Just like the above first answer.

4. In settings.py, I don't know your whole project structure, since the path here may decide whether you will get the output.
   I assume 'crawler' is a folder where you have another folder called 'spiders', and your spider code is in this 'spiders' folder. Your pipelines.py is under 'crawler' folder too
   For me, this worked:

   ```
   BOT_NAME = 'crawler'

   SPIDER_MODULES = ['crawler.spiders']
   NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'crawler.spiders'

   ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
   DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3

   ITEM_PIPELINES = {
      'crawler.pipelines.ScrapeNewsPipeline': 400,
   }
   ```
5. Finally, in order to run the code, I was using python terminal, cd to the code folder where you have crawler folder, then execute

   ```
   scrapy runspider crawler/spiders/my_test_spider.py
   ```

Although my test code is not 100% same as yours, hope this may help